# Shell Script to SSH to Multiple Remote Machines and Leave a Command Running

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, remote-access

I'm coding a distributed application and I need to spawn some process in multiple machines using `ssh`. The problem is that this command blocks the terminal, so I need that this command runs as a process. So that I can continue giving commands and moving to another machines.

#### For example

the command is something like:

```sh
make run
```

this command blocks my terminal, but I want to ssh to another machine and run this command, and another commands.

For now I'm with this script that is not working:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS=(ex1 ex2)
COMPILE_SCRIPT="make"
RUN_CHEFS="make run &"
CLIENT_SCRIPT="make client"

# Compile the project
ssh "${HOSTS[0]}" "${COMPILE_SCRIPT}"

# Run the command in the hosts
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS[*]} ; do
  ssh "${HOSTNAME}" "${RUN_CHEFS}"
done

ssh "${HOSTS[0]}" "${CLIENT_SCRIPT}"
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to use a utility such as [mussh](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mussh/), which lets you do things like:

```
mussh -l username -m -h host1 host2 host3 -c "make run"
```

-m flag means run concurrently.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I don't have `mussh` installed and I don't have permission to install it in these machines. :'(

Comment: mussh is a shell script, so you don't have to install anything as 'root'. Download the tar.gz package from the link above and find the 'mussh' script...

Comment: I'd be looking at ansible for this kind of thing